# show multiple google forms in same spreadsheet tab

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

i wish to present two forms results into a single spreadsheet tab in a ASE order (from old to new from both forms), just like how a chat room works.

i have tryed using this formula:
IMPORTRANGE("MY spreadsheet taB id ","a2:g100")

this formula works and shows both forms results. but doesn't show results in a time order as i wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the sort function solves your question.

```
=sort(A2:B,1,false)
```

I created this spreadsheet so you can see the results.

[show multiple google forms in same spreadsheet tab](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dPDrfz4bVKf374Ar3XEGHmL2tUYwasZ6osk7XAn7cgw/edit?usp=sharing)

In "A2:B", use your last column instead of "B". Do you think this helps?